# $.ajax POST works and $.ajax PUT does not while send a data to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

While making a ajax call with jQuery, if I use the POST method it works fine but while using the PUT method with no other changes it does not send the object data my question is why?

// works well

```
    function createMovie(){

      let m= new movie($("#name").val(),$("#director").val()+1,0);
     (function(){$.ajax({
        url: "../../server/api/api.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data:{table:'movies',
              adata:m
             },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
         }
        })
    }())
    }
```

// returns  Undefined index: adata and the same for table

```
    function updateMovie(){

      let m= new movie($("#name").val(),$("#director").val()+1,$("#id").val());

     (function(){$.ajax({
        url: "../../server/api/api.php",
        type: 'PUT',
        data:{table:'movies',
              adata:m
             },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
         }
        })
    }())
    }
```

here is the php

```
  $meth= strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
  $adata =  $_REQUEST['adata'];
  $table = $_REQUEST['table'];
```

Comment: Sounds like your problem is in the PHP, not in the javascript.  How about you post the relevant PHP?

Comment: Also, can you post the payload for your `put` request

Answer (score 0):

I found that $_REQUEST does not work for PUT and you have to create a put array yourself i found the answer in the link below.

[How to process PUT requests with PHP](https://joshtronic.com/2014/06/01/how-to-process-put-requests-with-php/)